# Django form __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument

Tags: django-forms

Hello, I'm trying to use a modified `__init__` form method, but I am encountering the following error:

```python
TypeError
__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'vUserProfile'
```

I need to pass `UserProfile` to my form, to get to `dbname` field, and I think this is a solution (my form code):

```python
class ClienteForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Cliente

def __init__(self, vUserProfile, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ClienteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["idcidade"].queryset = Cidade.objects.using(vUserProfile.dbname).all()
```

Calls to constructor `ClienteForm()` without POST are successful and show me the correct form. But when the form is submitted and the constructor is called with POST, I get the previously described error.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You've changed the signature of the form's `__init__` method so that `vUserProfile` is the first argument. But here:

```
formPessoa = ClienteForm(request.POST, instance=cliente, vUserProfile=profile)
```

you pass `request.POST` as the first argument - except that this will be interpreted as `vUserProfile`. And then you also try to pass `vUserProfile` as a keyword arg.

Really, you should avoid changing the method signature, and just get the new data from `kwargs`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    vUserProfile = kwargs.pop('vUserProfile', None)
```

Comment: Thanks very much! works fine now.. I stay signature is default.. and use your tip...

Comment: I have other problem now.. how can I pass this code to one inlineformset_factory ?

Comment: Great solution, thanks! Does anyone think there is a way to achieve the same without the kwargs trick? Imo it makes the init less user friendly, it would be great to be able to add explicit keyword arguments.

Answer (score 33):

For the help of those others who Google to here:  the error comes from **init** picking up the argument from both a positional argument and the default argument.   Daniel Roseman's is accurate for the question as asked.

This can be either:

1. You put the argument by position and then by keyword:

   ```
   class C():
     def __init__(self, arg): ...

   x = C(1, arg=2)   # you passed arg twice!
   ```
2. You forgot to put `self` as the first argument:

   ```
   class C():
      def __init__(arg):  ...

   x = C(arg=1)   # but a position argument (for self) is automatically 
                  # added by __new__()!
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the case with ModelForm, but need to check. For me, the solution was:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.vUserProfile = kwargs.get('vUserProfile', None)
    del kwargs['vUserProfile']
    super(ClienteForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields["idcidade"].queryset = Cidade.objects.using(self.vUserProfile.dbname).all()
```