# Django ModelForms __init__ kwargs create and update

Tags: django

I'm trying to get the request.user into a ModelForm.  I feel like I've tried all permutations of this from overloading the

```
__init__
```

argument (per [Django form, request.post and initial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994619/django-form-request-post-and-initial)) to trying to pass it as a kwargs (per [Django form __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322185/init-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument)).  I

It does seem like the kwargs is the best approach but I'm totally stymied by it.

Here's the ModelForm:

```
class DistListForm(ModelForm):
    members = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.none())
    class Meta:
        model = DistList
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'members', 'is_private']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DistListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        up = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        /.. etc  ../
```

Here's how the create function currently works:

```
def distlistcreate(request):
    user = {'user': request.user}
    form = DistListForm(**user)
    if request.method ==  'POST':
        form = DistListForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            distlist = form.save(commit=False)
            distlist.creator = request.user
            distlist.save()
            form.save_m2m()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('distlistsmy'))
    return render(request, 'distlistcreate.html',{'form':form})
```

which throws a TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'.  The update method is equally unhelpful:

```
def distlistupdate(request, object_id):
    distlist = get_object_or_404(DistList, id=object_id)
    form = DistListForm(user=request.user, instance=distlist)
    if request.method ==  'POST':
        form = DistListForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
```

It also throws the same error.

I've been banging my head against this wall for two hours now.  What is the correct way to pass a keyword argument into a ModelForm?

This is Django 1.6.1 if that makes a difference.

Comment: You need to "pop" user from kwargs BEFORE you pass kwargs to the super __init__

Comment: ARRRRGGGGHHHHH!!!!! $#HDFA$#@#H#$$!$HF  

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pop the user argument before call super() so it will no conflict wit the default arguments of ModelForm

```
class DistListForm(ModelForm):
    members = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Company.objects.none())
    class Meta:
        model = DistList
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'members', 'is_private']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(DistListForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just did exactly this yesterday, on Django 1.5, and I am able to do:

`def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):`

on my ModelForm.  Then I just use user without having to pop it from the kwargs.

Comment: The problem I had with that approach was getting the user from a post.  I couldn't get the args right DistListForm(request.POST, user=request.user).  Because you've changed around the order of initialization.  Didn't work for me, but if you've got the code working for the post I'd LOVE to see it.

Comment: My approach is using a class-based view, and I am having to override `get_form_kwargs` and do `kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})`.  The posts on this page are actually making me wonder how mine is working so well.  It seems the better approach is to explicitly grab the keyword argument with `kwargs.pop`.