# Get request.user in queryset in a ModelForm with a ModelChoiceField that contains a RadioSelect widget

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-queryset, modelform

I would like to ask the community the following regarding passing `request.user` to a `queryset` in `ModelForm`. My `ModelForm` is:

```
class goForm(ModelForm): 
    user_choice = goModelChoiceField(
            widget=forms.RadioSelect,
            queryset=Document.objects.all().filter(who_upload=request.user),
            empty_label=None,
            to_field_name='docfile',
            label = 'Please select'
            )            
    class Meta:
        model = go
        fields = ['user_choice']
```

With

```
class goModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
        def label_from_instance(self, obj):
            return  "'%s' uploaded on %s" % (obj.file_name, 
                obj.when_upload.date())
```

All the answers I have found refer to either passing `request.user` to `__init__` or populate the `goForm` in the view with the filtered selection. However nothing seems to work in my case since I have sub-classed the form to return a specific string and also I am using
the `RadioSelect` widget that specifically needs the `queryset` as an argument (I am not 100% sure about that). So how can I pass `request.user` in `user_choice` ?

Comment: Doing it in `__init__` is exactly the right solution, and the fact that you have a custom class is irrelevant. Please show what you have tried and the errors you got.

Comment: Please check the indentation of your code. Putting the `goModelChoiceField` inside your ModelForm is probably a bad idea (it makes the code confusing and stops you reusing it in other classes). Having `user_choice` defined inside `goModelChoiceField` is certainly wrong.

Comment: @Alasdair : yes I realized that, I moved `user_choice` outside `goModelChoiceForm` and inside `Meta` class. It is strange though how it works in both ways. Thank you.

Comment: The `user_choice` field shouldn't be defined in the Meta class either.

Comment: @Alasdair : It is the only place where the code works. If it is placed outside the `Meta` class then I would have to also move out the `goModelChoiceField` subclass and make it a class by itself. But this wouldn't make my code more sparse? I am asking... I am not experienced as you or @Daniel Roseman of course. Thank you again for your patience and time you spend. I appreciate that.

Comment: No, it won't work at all if it is in Meta: Django does not expect fields to be defined there. And you *should* make goModelChoiceField into a standalone class; nested classes offer no benefit in Python. Neither of these things has any impact on how you pass `request.user`, which still needs to be done in `__init__`.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman : Thank you, I will try again with `__init__`. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [model choice field docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships) show how you can set the queryset in the `__init__` method.

```
class goForm(ModelForm): 
    user_choice = goModelChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        queryset=None,
        empty_label=None,
        to_field_name='docfile',
        label = 'Please select'
        )            

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(goForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user_choice'].queryset = Document.objects.all().filter(who_upload=user)

    class Meta:
        model = go
        fields = ['user_choice']
```

Note that the `__init__` method takes the user as an argument now, so remember to pass it wherever you instantiate your form in your view. For example:

```
form = goForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. One last bit of advice - I recommend renaming your model to `Go`, your form to `GoForm` etc. Django models are usually capitalized and the lowercase form is used for an individual instance, for example `go = Go.objects.get(id=10)`.

Comment: Thank you very much `Alasdair`. If I may ask another question. Your solution although seems to render fine when there is a GET, when there is a POST it either gives a `non-keyword arg after keyword arg` when the sequence of the arguments is the one you gave in your solution (i.e.: (user=request.user, data=request.POST)` and by swapping the order it gives a `__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'user'`. I suspect I should keep the first order but how can I escape this error? Thanks again `Alasdair`.

Comment: It seems that the solution to the above is not to change the signature of the `__init__` but get `user` with `user = kwargs.pop('user', None)` (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322185/init-got-multiple-values-for-keyword-argument) for a reference), that is why I edited your answer.

Comment: You can make the code work by either including user in the `__init__` signature, or popping it from kwargs. You shouldn't get a `non-keyword arg after keyword arg` with my code if you provide all arguments as keyword arguments.